# Poset dimension change when adding a point

Tags: order-theory

If a single point is added or removed from a poset, its [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_dimension) stays the same or changes by $1$. How to prove it?

I heard that it could be proven using [Łoś's theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LosTheorem.html), but, **despite trying**, I can't obtain a proof from this hint (nor any other proof).

My motivation is mainly to understand how Łoś's theorem works by looking at its application to a problem which isn't very general, yet non-trivial. (Other answers, not relying on Łoś's theorem, are welcome too, though, enabling comparison possibly giving better understanding of what the application of Łoś's theorem actually contributes here.)